# react native - Camera Roll returned uri does not have file's extension

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, camera-roll

React native has a good lib like CameraRoll which allow us to access the media files of phones. However, the returned uri is missing the extension:

```
{ node: 
  { timestamp: 1344461389.8,
   type: 'image', <= it is used to be 'image/png' instead of 'image'
   group_name: 'Camera Roll',
   location: 
    { altitude: 0,
      longitude: -14.538611666666666,
      latitude: 64.752895,
      heading: 0,
      speed: 0.8999988197665498 },
   image: 
    { width: 1668,
      uri: 'ph://99D53A1F-FEEF-40E1-8BB3-7DD55A43C8B7/L0/001', <= there is no file's extension
      height: 2500,
      isStored: true,
      playableDuration: 0 } } },
```

If you know a way to get the extension or any work around in this case, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a work around, the returned extension is not pretty but it is useable:

From the file RNCCameraRollManager.m:

## Please add these 2 lines

```
NSString *const extension = [asset valueForKey: @"uniformTypeIdentifier"];
```

[image]

## and

```
@"extension": extension,
```

[image]

Now you have the extension.

Here is the environment:

"@react-native-community/cameraroll": "1.0.3", 
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.5"

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using the expo-media-library
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library

```
     async myFunc() {
     let uri = "ph://ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED/L0/001"
     let myAssetId = uri.slice(5);
     let returnedAssetInfo = await MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(myAssetId);
     returnedAssetInfo // you will have all the information in here
```

}        }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not using expo, but sure I will check if we can "npm" this lib

Answer (score 1):

I added a boost to the camera roll package. You can use it **after version 5.2.0.** You can find the details here.
https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll/pull/440

**Now you can use it like this;**

```js
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
     include: ['fileExtension'],
})
```